# display a jqgrid on click of a row on a jqgrid

Tags: java, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

This page has to be writen in JSP and java

I want to display a jqgrid when i click a row on the jqgrid. Two ideas,

In the first page, i have to display a list in a jqgrid and when the user click a row on the grid

1) the page should be faded and another grid has to be pop up showing the details on another grid. on click of cancel, the pop up grid has to be closed and the background grid has to be visible.
2) another jqgrid should be displayed on top of the actual jqgrid right below the row clicked. Just like a context menu on right click of a jqgrid row.

Please guide me. I am new to jquery and jqgrid and find hard to achieve this.

Comment: okay if user clicks on a row of first grid, do u want to display that row info in new grid or you want to display some other data?

Comment: i want to display some other data based on the values on the row that the user selected.

Comment: okay just wait for 10 mins, i'm preparing answer for you..

Answer (score 2):

so this is how it is going to work...

onSelectRow:function(id){

var data=jQuery("#gridFirstGrid").jqGrid('getRowData',id); //suppose you have name and company in first grid

var name=data.Name;
var company=data.Company;

//there is another way(getCell) also to directly get Name and Company based on id

jQuery("#gridFirstGrid").fadeOut("slow").

load second grid here with the data you want to pick...suppose if you want to get some data from database based on Name or company, send an ajax request from here and return the data in json format and bind it to second grid the same way you were doing in first grid. Implement a custom button in second grid and on the click of the button(cancel) fadeOut the second grid and fade in the first one.

to know how to send ajax request  check this link [OnClickButton function parameter for MultiSelect jqgrid MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658625/onclickbutton-function-parameter-for-multiselect-jqgrid-mvc3/11662959#11662959), and how to add a custom button check this http://trirand.net/examples/grid/selection/selectedrow_client/default.aspx   it is outside the grid, but you can use that also

Comment: bind the data to second grid in success parameter of ajax request, you will get the response here what you were sending from controller..